# Oracle - some of polish characters are not display

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, workflow-foundation, odp

I have an app in Windows Form using Oracle Data Provider, oracle version 12c. On Windows 7 all polish characters are ok, but after migration on Windows 10 some characters are ok, but some other are displaying as strange signs, for example

> informuj**š**ca

except

> informuj**ą**ca

Characters which are not display good: ą, ś, ź

In C# I set environment:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("NLS_LANG", "AMERICAN_AMERICA.EE8ISO8859P2");//POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250");
```

The only answer I found on internet is parameter which is commented, but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: Which provider/driver do you use?

Comment: Oracle.DataAccess - 4.112.3 and
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess - 4.122.18.3

Comment: I don't think you get the same problem with both providers, because ODP.NET Managed Provider does not depend on `NLS_LANG` settings, see [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/featGlobal.htm#ODPNT437). ODP.NET Unmanaged driver inherits `NLS_LANG` value, do you set the NLS_LANG after connecting to database? In best case you should set it before you start the process.

Comment: aff, I don't really know what is the reason of this issue